# Setting Folder Permisions using C#

Tags: c#

I am completing a tool that will update clients web applications to the latest iteration of our code. The Utility is a Windows C# application.  Once the old files are archived and the new files are put in place I need to set some folder permissions for several folders.

The code below will add the NETWORK Service account to those folders that need to be changed however it does not actually set the permissions.  In other words I can look at the folder security and NETWORK SERVICE is added however no permissions are added.  The code is shown below:

```
public bool SetFolderPermissions(string folderName, out string errorMessage)
{
  bool returnVal = false;
  string returnMessage = string.Empty;
  DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folderName);
  try
  {
   DirectorySecurity dirSecurity = dirInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
   CanonicalizeDacl(dirSecurity);
   dirSecurity.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("NETWORK SERVICE", FileSystemRights.Modify, InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit, PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow));
   dirInfo.SetAccessControl(dirSecurity);
   returnVal = true;
   errorMessage = "sucess";
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    errorMessage = "Error occured while setting the permissions for" + folderName + ": " + e.Message;
  }
  return returnVal;
}

static void CanonicalizeDacl(NativeObjectSecurity objectSecurity)
{
  if (objectSecurity == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("objectSecurity"); }
  if (objectSecurity.AreAccessRulesCanonical) { return; }

  // A canonical ACL must have ACES sorted according to the following order:
  //   1. Access-denied on the object
  //   2. Access-denied on a child or property
  //   3. Access-allowed on the object
  //   4. Access-allowed on a child or property
  //   5. All inherited ACEs 
  RawSecurityDescriptor descriptor = new RawSecurityDescriptor(objectSecurity.GetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm(AccessControlSections.Access));

  List<CommonAce> implicitDenyDacl = new List<CommonAce>();
  List<CommonAce> implicitDenyObjectDacl = new List<CommonAce>();
  List<CommonAce> inheritedDacl = new List<CommonAce>();
  List<CommonAce> implicitAllowDacl = new List<CommonAce>();
  List<CommonAce> implicitAllowObjectDacl = new List<CommonAce>();

  foreach (CommonAce ace in descriptor.DiscretionaryAcl)
  {
    if ((ace.AceFlags & AceFlags.Inherited) == AceFlags.Inherited) { inheritedDacl.Add(ace); }
    else
    {
      switch (ace.AceType)
      {
        case AceType.AccessAllowed:
          implicitAllowDacl.Add(ace);
          break;

        case AceType.AccessDenied:
          implicitDenyDacl.Add(ace);
          break;

        case AceType.AccessAllowedObject:
          implicitAllowObjectDacl.Add(ace);
          break;

        case AceType.AccessDeniedObject:
          implicitDenyObjectDacl.Add(ace);
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  Int32 aceIndex = 0;
  RawAcl newDacl = new RawAcl(descriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.Revision, descriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.Count);
  implicitDenyDacl.ForEach(x => newDacl.InsertAce(aceIndex++, x));
  implicitDenyObjectDacl.ForEach(x => newDacl.InsertAce(aceIndex++, x));
  implicitAllowDacl.ForEach(x => newDacl.InsertAce(aceIndex++, x));
  implicitAllowObjectDacl.ForEach(x => newDacl.InsertAce(aceIndex++, x));
  inheritedDacl.ForEach(x => newDacl.InsertAce(aceIndex++, x));

  if (aceIndex != descriptor.DiscretionaryAcl.Count)
  {
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Fail("The DACL cannot be canonicalized since it would potentially result in a loss of information");
    return;
  }

  descriptor.DiscretionaryAcl = newDacl;
  objectSecurity.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm(descriptor.GetSddlForm(AccessControlSections.Access), AccessControlSections.Access);
}
```

}

Could anyone please point me in the right direction or offer a fix to my issue?

update, I realized that the code is actually setting permissions but it is only showing under Special permissions, is this normal? While it does set these special permissions, It does not allow the access that I need i.e. the web application cannot upload a file to the specified location.

Comment: Shouldn't it be called something like, `TrySetFolderPermissions`? Does the `errormessage` out parameter contain any information? Where do you seem to be exiting from your `CanonicalizeDacl` method? Did you debug already?

Comment: The errorMessage out returns success.  Since no error occurred.  If I do not call CanonicalizeDacl then I get "The Access Control List is not canonical" and the NETWORK SERVICE account is not added to the folder security list.